# Maven cobertura plugin - one report for multimodule project

Tags: maven-2, cobertura

I'm using maven cobertura plugin to report code coverage in my multimodule project.

The problem is that I don't know how to generate one report for all modules in project.

So far I have generated separate reports for every module, but it would be nice to have one report for whole project.

My parent pom configuration:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>clean</goal>
                    <goal>cobertura</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is currently not supported, see [MCOBERTURA-65](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-65). But the issue has a patch attached, maybe try it. But my suggestion would be to use something like [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) to aggregate metrics.

Comment: It is now supported. See my answer.

Answer (score 18):

The plugin has been updated since this question was asked (and last answered) to now enable aggregated reporting, via the `aggregate` configuration property in the parent POM.

This produces the aggregated coverage report at `target/site/cobertura/index.html` which will include all modules.

(Each module will also have it's own report produced, if that is of any use.)

**Parent pom.xml**

```
<modules>
    <module>moduleA</module>
    <module>moduleB</module>
    <module>moduleC</module>
<modules>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <check/>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
...
</build>
```

Comment: Should I run `mvn cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.report.format=xml` commmand on parent module and It will generate aggregated report in parent module?

Comment: I ran `mvn cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.report.format=xml` command on parent package it aggregates the reports of child modules but it do not show coverage of a class in child maven module of this parent module, if that class is covered by class from different child maven module of this parent module.

Comment: It sounds like you have one module testing the classes of another module. This does not sound like a good idea. A module should contain tests for its own classes. You should submit a separate question if this is not the case.

Comment: This can also be done via without editing the pom file:
`mvn cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.aggregate=true -Dcobertura.report.format=xml`

You can change the report format as you wish.

According to the cobertura maven plugin's github repo, this feature is available 
[since v2.5](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura/CoberturaReportMojo.java#L126) (commit [64a8823](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/commit/64a8823866b4c8be74a44383162088d616c65185#diff-e4171be1b77f9a9b331e21a0661c1433R126)).

Comment: Hi, Is there a possibility to group module results in a single report ? May be under module name.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Hudson as a Continuous Integration tool. 
The Cobertura plugin allows me to see code coverage of all of the child modules when checking on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins Cobertura plugin aggregates the report automatically but if you are interested in  the coverage file itself for some other reasons  you can do by following below procedure:

1. Download Cobertura from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cobertura/files/latest/download?source=files)
2. Go to your project workspace -> find all the `.ser` files and rename them

   ```
   (i=0; find . | grep cobertura.ser$ | while read line;do echo $line; cp -i $line cobertura$i.ser;i=$(($i+1));done;)
   ```
3. use `cobertura-merge.sh` to generate global `.ser` file

   ```
   ~/cobertura-2.0.3/cobertura-merge.sh --datafile cobertura.ser cobertura*.ser
   ```
4. use  `cobertura-report.sh` to generate report on global .ser file

   ```
   ~/cobertura-2.0.3/cobertura-report.sh ./cobertura.ser --destination ./ --format xml
   ```

You will have the global `coverage.xml` generated in the current directory.
You can use it for any kind of processing further.

Comment: This can also be done via command line only using maven:
`mvn cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.aggregate=true -Dcobertura.report.format=xml`

You can change the report format as you wish.

According to the cobertura maven plugin's github repo, this feature is available 
[since v2.5](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura/CoberturaReportMojo.java#L126) (commit [64a8823](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/commit/64a8823866b4c8be74a44383162088d616c65185#diff-e4171be1b77f9a9b331e21a0661c1433R126)).