# Integrated test coverage reports

Tags: java, maven, cobertura, maven-site-plugin

I need to generate a final report that is a mix of all the reports from all the projects that i have generated using the maven-site-plugin and cobertura.

Below you can find the code in both the build and reporting

```
<!-- this is in the build part -->
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                            <formats>
                                <format>html</format>
                                <format>xml</format>
                            </formats>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


<!-- this is in the reporting part -->    
 <reporting>
 <plugins>

   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
            <check></check>
            <aggregate>true</aggregate>
            <formats>
                <format>html</format>
                <format>xml</format>
            </formats>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>

 </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: is ur all the projects comes under single parent pom?

Comment: yes they are under same parent pom

Comment: possible duplicate [Maven cobertura plugin - one report for multimodule project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768517/maven-cobertura-plugin-one-report-for-multimodule-project)

Comment: I went through that question but did not workout for me. i was able to generate few reports and the links in the aggregate html in parent pom points to a different directory which is not being created.

Comment: Could u plz post ur parent pom.xml file content?